# Stop re-firing of Assignment Rule, skip Default Case Owner and assign Case Owner from Code

Tags: apex, after-trigger, assignment-rules

I'm trying to update case owner in after insert trigger but assignment rule is running as per order execution, if criteria doesn't match ,default owner from support settings is being set as an owner.
When record get created into Salesforce following Order of execution works:
System Validation Rules
Apex Before Triggers
Custom Validation Rules
Duplicate Rules
Apex After Triggers
Assignment Rules

Comment: You can move the code which updates the case owner from trigger to a future method and call that method from your after insert trigger. So your assignment rule will change to default owner and the future will execute asynchronously from current transaction and change to your desired owner.

Comment: @VigneshwaranG Thank you, it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the code which updates the case owner from trigger to a future method and call that method from your after insert trigger. So your assignment rule will change to default owner and the future will execute asynchronously from current transaction and change to your desired owner.